# Bi-nominal expansion of 3 terms

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Find the coefficient of $x^{17}$ in the expansion of $(3x^7 + 2x^5 -1)^{20}$

I'm stuck in handling this question as I do know how to solve it when it has 2 terms.
But now it has 3.

I have no idea where to begin...

Comment: You can do it a number of ways, but if you don't want to have to learn something new, then recognize that $(3x^7+2x^5-1)^{20}=((3x^7+2x^5)-1)^{20}$

Comment: In how many ways can you write $17$ as a sum of $5$'s and $7$'s?

Comment: I tried using your method and got stuck at the second part where I had $(3x^7 + 2x^5)^{20-n}$


I further expand the derived expression and had 2 unknowns

Comment: Let $y=(3x^7+2x^5)$.  Making this substitution, we have the expression expands as $\binom{20}{0}(-1)^{20}y^0+\binom{20}{1}(-1)^{19}y^1+\binom{20}{2}(-1)^{18}y^2+\binom{20}{3}(-1)^{17}y^3+\dots$.  Can you see how to continue?  Can you recognize that $(3x^7+2x^5)^4,(3x^7+2x^5)^5,(3x^7+2x^5)^6,\dots$ each cannot possibly contribute to the final coefficient of $x^{17}$?  Where then should all of your attention be drawn?

Comment: @JMoravitz I understand thanks!. One query is that given the expansion requirements is small, I can manually do it out all right?

Answer (score 0):

=the coefficient of $x^{17}$ in $(2x^5-1)^{20}$

$+\binom{20}13^1\cdot$ the coefficient of $x^{17-7}$ in $(2x^5-1)^{20-1}$

$+\binom{20}23^2\cdot$ the coefficient of $x^{17-2\cdot7}$ in $(2x^5-1)^{20-2}$

Comment: How did you get to this process? Is it a fancy binomial expansion, or some really abstract math trick?

Comment: @ChristopherMarley it is essentially the same hint as I gave above, except having broken it up as $(3x^7+(2x^5-1))^{20}$ instead.  Its just repeated application of binomial expansion.

Comment: @JMoravitz I tried using your method and got stuck at the second part where I had (3x7+2x5)20−n I further expand the derived expression and had 2 unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

We can apply the binomial theorem twice in order to find the coeffcient. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ of an expression.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{17}]}&\color{blue}{(3x^7+2x^5-1)^{20}}\\
> &=[x^{17}]\sum_{k=0}^{20}\binom{20}{k}(3x^7)^k(2x^5-1)^{20-k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\binom{20}{0}3^0[x^{17}](2x^5-1)^{20}+\binom{20}{1}3^1[x^{10}](2x^5-1)^{19}\\
> &\qquad +\binom{20}{2}3^2[x^3](2x^5-1)^{18}\tag{2}\\
> &=3\binom{20}{1}[x^{10}]\sum_{j=0}^{19}\binom{19}{j}(2x^5)^j(-1)^{19-j}\tag{3}\\
> &=-3\binom{20}{1}\binom{19}{2}2^2\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=-41\,040}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the binomial theorem once to $(3x^7+(2x^5-1))^{20}$.
- In (2) we observe that the term $(3x^7)^k$ contributes to $[x^{17}]$ only when $k=0,1,2$. We also apply the rule $[x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)$.
- In (3) we note that expanding $(2x^5-1)^n$ gives only exponents of $x$ which are a multiple of $5$. We can therefore stick to the middle summand with $[x^{10}]$ and we apply the binomial theorem again.
- In (4) we select the coefficient of $x^j$ accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The trinomial expansion:
$$(a+b+c)^n=\sum_{\ \ \ \ \ i,j,k\\ i+j+k=n}{n\choose {i,j,k}}a^ib^jc^k,$$
where ${n\choose {i,j,k}}=\frac{n!}{i!j!k!}$.

If applied to the given trinomial:
$$(3x^7 + 2x^5 -1)^{20}=\sum_{\ \ \ \ \ i,j,k\\ i+j+k=20}{20\choose {i,j,k}}(3x^7)^i(2x^5)^j(-1)^k.$$
The exponent of $x$ will be $17$ when:
$$7i+5j=17 \Rightarrow (i,j,k)=(1,2,17).$$
Hence:
$${20\choose {1,2,17}}3^12^2(-1)^{17}=\frac{20!}{1!2!17!}(-12)=-41040.$$